# How can I retrieve through an API *Live Metrics* of Microsoft Application Insights

Tags: monitoring, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-functions-core-tools

I monitor the execution of an Azure function using the Live Metrics Stream management UI as seen below:[image: Live Metrics Management]
Some of these metrics can be retrieved through the [Application Insights REST API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart). However, metrics concerning overall health data, or Servers data, return a null value. For example,the `performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage` endpoint produces the following output when probed:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
  "value": {
    "start": "2018-10-16T11:20:37.366Z",
    "end": "2018-10-16T12:20:37.366Z",
    "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
      "avg": null
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the information appearing under the overall health and servers rows in the UI, through the API?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve live data? Or historical data?

Comment: Any of these types, although recent historical data would be preferable (and live data optimal).

Comment: @ZakiMa, the problem is that the return value is null as atsag metioned in his post when use [this](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/metrics) for test(The application id and key is mine, and in metric ID textbox select performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage). The wired thing is that one of my app insight can return non-null value. But if I create a new application insight, do some requests, then try to fetch performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage, it returns null(I can see it does have value in live metrics).

Comment: I understood the question as "how get the information appearing under the overall health and servers rows in the UI through the API". One way to achieve this is to run a query from an answer. If the question was about why this particular metric returns null then I misunderstood. @astsag?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to retrieve live data at the moment.

For retrieving historical data you need the following.

1) First to come up with a query which returns data you're interested in. Here is an example (shows Request Count, 95th CPU, 95th Request Duration by Server):

```
let start = ago(1d);
requests
| where timestamp > start
| summarize ["RequestCount"]=count(), ["Duration"]=percentile(duration, 95) by cloud_RoleInstance
| join (
    performanceCounters
    | where timestamp > start
    | where name == "% Processor Time Normalized"
    | where category == "Process"
    | summarize ["CPU"]=percentile(value, 95) by cloud_RoleInstance
) on cloud_RoleInstance
| project cloud_RoleInstance, RequestCount, Duration, CPU
| order by RequestCount
```

You can adjust Analytics query the way you need.

Example output:

[image]

2) Use the [API reference](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart) to run "Query"

Comment: Thank you ZakiMa. I run this query on a fresh Azure function, having invoked it several times. Yet, the output list is `"rows": []` (when the query is run in the API reference mentioned in step 2) and when the query is run in the application insights UI (at analytics.applicationinsights.io/subscriptions/...) the output is `"No results found"`. Perhaps this is not a methodology which can apply to functions...

Comment: Most likely this performance counter is not available in Azure Functions. Do you see CPU/Memory live data for azure functions?

Comment: you can specify "leftouter" join: "join kind=leftouter" - then you'll still get a list of servers but CPU column will be null if not available

Comment: To check which performance counters are available you can run this query: performanceCounters
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| summarize count() by name

Comment: Thank you for coming back! I tried the last query, but unfortunately it returns an empty list (as above) - as if no performance counters are available. As you can see in the "Servers" section of the image in the question, in the UI you get metrics for the CPU and Memory consumption