# Retrieve Azure AppInsights Live Metrics through API

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

There is an one year old question [How can I retrieve through an API *Live Metrics* of Microsoft Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839073/how-can-i-retrieve-through-an-api-live-metrics-of-microsoft-application-insigh) about is it possible to pull LiveMetrics data that appInsights generate for the application trough some API

Right now i don't see anything live related in the official documentation - https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference . And the answer for old question was also that there is no any way to get them.

But maybe someone knows if AppInsights team plans were changed in this year and they are working on that API?

It might be really useful to pull that data in realtime through API to own alerting\metrics system to process data from different microservices\applications and display them in aggregated way in realtime. 
As example we can build something like [OpServer](https://github.com/opserver/Opserver) has but based on different applications and their AppInsights data [image: https://i.imgur.com/VnBnUd4.png].

As right now there is no any way to get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I work in Application Insights team at Microsoft.

LiveMetrics data is not persistently stored anywhere, and there is no API to retrieve it. The data is collected only when someone is actively on the Live Metrics portal page. The moment browser window is closed, data is gone as well.

If your goal is to get metrics/other in real-time, then you can do that by implementing own `ITelemetryProcessor`. Most people use `ITelemetryProcessor` to "filter" out unwanted telemetry. But that is not a rule. All telemetry passes through `TelemetryProcessor`, and you can chose to filter the data or do something else with it. In your case you want to send it instantly to some real-time service. In fact, LiveMetrics (internally known as QuickPulse) is implemented as a TelemetryProcessor. (https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/WEB/Src/PerformanceCollector/Perf.Shared/QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor.cs#L158)

General doc about TelemetryProcessor:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c

Comment: Thanks for the answer! QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor implementation was super useful to get understanding how LiveMetrics works. And it's pretty nice idea to do periodical `Ping` and push data to QuickPulse only if someone opened that LiveMetrics page and Ping returned different state. It makes sense for us to have custom ITelemetryProcessor that will push live data to internal system, so thanks again!